# Regex to extract username from String

Tags: string, bash, shell

input string example - #J219568abpwrk1

I want to extract the string "abpwrk1" from above.

The string will always begin with #J followed by 5 or 6 digits. It indicates job number.
What is followed by this is username that I want to extract.
Username can be alphanumeric but it can be assumed that it will always begin with an alphabet.

Tried below :

```bash
a="#J219568abpwrk1"; a="${a#*[a-z]}"; echo $a;
# => bpwrk1
```

I need complete username.

Can any expert help with this in bash.

Answer (score 5):

You may use extended glob:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

s='#J219568abpwrk1'
echo "${s/\#J+([0-9])/}"
# => abpwrk1
```

**More details**

Extended globbing as described by the [bash man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html):

```
?(pattern-list)   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
*(pattern-list)   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
+(pattern-list)   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
@(pattern-list)   Matches one of the given patterns
!(pattern-list)   Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Here a pattern-list is a list of items separated by a vertical bar "|" (aka the pipe symbol). If you look at these you can see why the leading character was chosen as it matches what is used in regular expression syntax:

```
  Bash              Regular Expression
?(pattern-list)   (...|...)?
*(pattern-list)   (...|...)*
+(pattern-list)   (...|...)+
@(pattern-list)   (...|...)    [@ not a RE syntax]
!(pattern-list)   "!" used as for negative assertions in RE syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

There is special syntax for regex in bash:

```
var='#J219568abpwrk1'
reg='#J[0-9]+(.*)'
[[ $var =~ $reg ]] && username=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo $username
abpwrk1
```

Here BASH_REMATCH is a build-in array for bash regex results.

Answer (score 2):

**Direct Answer**

Using Ubuntu with (posix?) grep regular expressions.

**How it Works**

- Starts with `#J`

  `#J`
- digits 5,6

  `#J[0-9]{5,6}`
- (Capture The Username)

  `#J[0-9]{5,6}([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9])`

The -o (only) flag to group only shows the captured group.

`echo "#J219568abpwrk1" | grep -oE '#J[0-9]{5,6}([a-zA-Z][a-ZA-Z0-9]+)'`

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $a =~ J[0-9]+(.*) ]]
then
  username=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  if [[ -n $username ]]
  then
    echo Unsername empty 1>&2
  fi
else
  echo "$a does not match the required pattern" 1>&2
fi
```

This does not verify that there are 5 or 6 digits after the initial `J`. If you want to do this, replace the `+` by `{5,6}`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to present some added diversity of methodology...

The other methods here are probably better, but if you are one of those folk that avoid extended globs and regex matching, you can still do it pretty simply and efficiently with a temp var as long as user names always start with a lowercase letter.

```
$: y=${x%%[a-z]*}; # assign Job ID to y by *removing* the UID
$: echo ${x#$y}    # remove the job id to output the UID
abpwrk1
```

It's indirect, but in this case, easy and effective.

If you prefer built-in obfuscation, an unnecessary subshell, and limiting yourself to ASCII/UTF-8, (etc) then by all means try this monstrosity:

```
$: echo ${x:$((8-( $( printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}" )>96 ) ))}
abpwrk1
```

That's a little dense, so let's break it out:

```
$: x='#J654321abpwrk1'                           # Job ID is 6 digits
$: echo ${x:7:1}                                 # what's that character?
1
$: $ printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}"                    # ASCII ordinal? 
49
$: echo $(( $( printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}" )>96 ))  # lowercase letter?(nope)
0
$: echo ${x:$((8-( $( printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}" )>96 ) ))} # correct offset
abpwrk1

$ x='#J54321abpwrk1'                             # Job ID is 5 digits
$: echo ${x:7:1}                                 
a
$: printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}"
97
$: echo $(( $( printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}" )>96 ))
1
$: echo ${x:$((8-( $( printf '%2d' "'${x:7:1}" )>96 ) ))}
abpwrk1
```

Sometimes a ***bad*** example is handy. :)

But honestly, just use `shopt -s extglob` or `BASH_REMATCH`.